# Add fields to Keystone.js Model Class using json file

Tags: json, model, keystonejs

I wonder if it's possible add fields to a collection, in Keystone.js, using information saved in a json file.
I'll show you my problem:

instead of

```
Collection.add({
    aaa: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    bbb: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    ccc: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
}); // this works!
```

I want to add fields in this way:

```
json_model = require(process.env.PWD + process.env.JSON_MODELS +'/collection.json'),   //path of json file
var tmp_json = modelFromJsonFunc.json4model(json_model);
Projects.add(tmp_json);
```

The output is

```
{
    aaa: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    bbb: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    ccc: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
}

                                                     ...
```

Using mongo shell I see this collection has no fields!
Why doesn't works?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: keystone uses mongoose under the hood so you can search for answers for mongoose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504446/defining-a-mongoose-schema-on-the-fly-from-a-json-formatted-description

Comment: @HarryMoreno's comment above is absolutely correct. The answer in the question he's recommending works for Mongoose schemas, but does not take into consideration Keystone Types.

Answer (score 0):

@Michele if run the code in your example as you claim you're doing you wouldn't get a collection with no fields, you would get an error.

In the following line of code:

```
json_model = require(process.env.PWD + process.env.JSON_MODELS +'/collection.json'),   //path of json file
```

`require()` uses `JSON.parse()` to evaluate `.json` files. What you show above is not valid `JSON` and would cause an error.

Because the schema contains data types, some of which are specific to Keystone, the file needs to be evaluated as `JavaScript` and not `JSON`. One possible way to accomplish what want is to read your `.json` file, wrap it in an IIFE which returns the data read form the `.json`file, parse it using `eval()`, and return the result.

Here's an example of how I would do it ...

*requireJsonSchema.js*

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types,
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function (pathname) {
    try {
        var data = fs.readFileSync(pathname);
        return eval('(function() { return ' + data + '; })();');
    } catch(e) {
        return {};
    }
}
```

*Test.js*

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types,
    requireJsonSchema = require('/path/to/requireJsonSchema'),

var Test = new keystone.List('Test');
var jsonSchema = requireJsonSchema('/path/to/Test.json');

Test.add(jsonSchema);

Test.register();
```